# newFixedThreadPool slower than single threaded program

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, executorservice, executors

Here's a quick rundown of my predicament. I am learning multi-threading and therefore decided to make a thumbnail creator program to process around 300 images.
At first, I did all the thumbnail creation on a single thread and that took around 99 seconds.
So I figured that using `newFixedThreadPool()` would make the program faster. I have heard that using `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()` is less expensive than manually creating threads.
So  I did:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
```

4 being the number of cores on my machine.

The strange thing is that doing this made the program slower. 
When I used  one thread in the `newFixedThreadPool`, the tasks were completed in around 118 seconds.
When I used 4 threads, the tasks were completed in around 99 seconds. A few milliseconds slower than the initial single threaded operation.
When I used 10 threads, the time taken was around 110 seconds.

I have absolutely no idea on how to make the program faster. I was thinking that using 4 threads is optimal and it would allow for the work to be done in around a quarter of the time the single threaded operation took.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what can be done? Here is my (very ugly code)

```
public class Thumbnails {
    protected static BufferedImage image = null;
    protected static BufferedImage outBM;
    protected static Graphics2D g2d;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        File f = new File("/home/njengah/Media/Images");

        File[] myPics = f.listFiles();// list of all images folder

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

        for (int i = 0; i < myPics.length; i++) {
            executor.submit(new Thumbnails().new ImgProcessor(myPics[i]));

        }
        System.out.println(" all tasks submitted ");

        executor.shutdown();


        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(" image processing completed.");

        long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("time taken to process all images: "+(stop - start));

    }

    // this handles the processing of a single image
    protected static void singleImageProcessor(File onePic) throws IOException {
        image = ImageIO.read(onePic);

        outBM = new BufferedImage((int) (image.getWidth() * 0.1), (int) (image.getHeight() * 0.1), image.getType());

        g2d = outBM.createGraphics();

        g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, (int) (image.getWidth() * 0.1), (int) (image.getHeight() * 0.1), null);
        g2d.dispose();

        ImageIO.write(outBM, onePic.getName().split("\\.")[1], new File("/home/njengah/Downloads/resized/" + onePic.getName()));
    }

    private class ImgProcessor implements Runnable {

        File onePic;

         public ImgProcessor(File onePic) {
             this.onePic = onePic;

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // this runs one task
            System.out.println("starting");
            try {
                singleImageProcessor(onePic); // single task

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } // to make it shut up

            System.out.println("finished");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have two cores with multithreading or 4 real cores? If you have only two cores, it's better to set the thread pool to 2 only. Virtual cores won't help you too much with this. Context switching between threads is expensive operation so, as you go above your number of physical cores, it will become slower and slower.

Comment: Your performance is not limited by CPU, it's limited by Disk I/O. Multi-threading the program just means you now have 4 threads waiting on the hard disk, instead of only one thread. Run your single-threaded program again, and look at CPU usage. You'll see it's not even using one core in full.

Comment: @NándorElődFekete Its unbelievable. Your solution works. The time taken is down to 69 seconds. Thanks